# LibGdx image loads on Desktop but not Android

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

When I try to load SOME images on android I crash with the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 50638
Process: com.greenpipestudios.seedpeople, PID: 28277
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: gui/up.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.greenpipestudios.seedpeople.ResourceManager.loadGuiImages(ResourceManager.java:188)
```

I am loading all images through my `ResourceManager.java` module. All of the images for sprites that are loaded through this method work fine:

```
public void loadImages(int sprite_id){

    try{
        if(images.get(sprite_id) != null)return;
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        return;
    }

    int imwidth = dimensions.get(sprite_id)[0];
    int imheight = dimensions.get(sprite_id)[1];;   
    int[] numFrames = frameCounts.get(sprite_id);
    int numSprites = numFrames.length;
    ArrayList<TextureRegion[]> sprites = new ArrayList<TextureRegion[]>();


    try {
        Texture spritesheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(imgpaths.get(sprite_id)));
        TextureRegion[][] sheet = TextureRegion.split(spritesheet,imwidth,imheight);

        for(int i = 0; i < numSprites; i++){
            TextureRegion[] sprite = new TextureRegion[frameCounts.get(sprite_id)[i]];
            for(int j = 0; j < frameCounts.get(sprite_id)[i]; j++){
                sheet[i][j].flip(false, true);
                sprite[j] = sheet[i][j];
            }
            sprites.add(sprite);
        }




        images.set(sprite_id, sprites);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The line `Texture spritesheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(imgpaths.get(sprite_id)));` is what loads fine on both Android and Desktop. `imgpaths.get(sprite_id)` returns a string such as `"sprites/player.png"`.

The following method crashes on the specified line on android, but works fine on desktop:

`btnUp = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.local("gui/up.png")));`

```
public void loadGuiImages(){
    btnUp = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.local("gui/up.png")));
    btnAction = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.local("gui/action.png")));
    btnPause = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.local("gui/pause.png")));
}
```

As you can see, the Texture constructor **Texture(FileHandle f)** is getting invoked with similar paramaters but crashes in one instance and not the other.

NOTE: I tested loading the texture on its own (not inside of the TextureRegion constructor) and still got the same error. Also the images are power-of-two dimensions but they shouldn't even have to be.

Comment: NOTE: I have confirmed that they are packaged into the .apk so this is NOT an eclipse asset sync error.

Answer (score 0):

You say the Gdx.files.internal method works on desktop and android, but the Gdx.files.local doesn't on android. Do you have any part of your code where a Gdx.files.local call on android works?

I think internal is where assets should reside, and local is meant for smaller files (ex: game state).

Different OSs treat the internal/local locations slightly differently. This could be why things "work" on desktop and not on android. Your interchanging of Gdx.files calls may be pointing you to different places.

Comment: I feel awfully dumb because I spent a while working on this game (36 hours without sleep) and couldn't notice my own typo. I meant to use internal but screwed up. Sorry for the waste of a post.

Comment: I'm sure you're not the first (or will be the last) person to code in a marathon session and type non-compiler detected errors. Hopefully you got it straightened out.

Comment: Everything looks good now, but honestly this question should probably be removed.